# Assigning text box values dynamically in a loop in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have 20+ text boxes that are all named like:
TxtCustom1
TxtCustom2
TxtCustom3 
and so on...

I want to be able to assign those text boxes values in a loop by building the text box var name dynamically with a int concatenated so that my loop would be something like this pseudo code:

```
For Each pair In Dictionary
TxtCustom{pair.key}.Text = pair.Value 
Next
```

Is building names dynamically like this possible in vb.net, how would something like this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it would be better to use some kind of control like a grid  for this than a series of textboxes with names following a template, but here is how you do it based on the scenario you discussed.

```
For Each pair In Dictionary
   Me.Controls(String.format("TxtCustom{0}",pair.key)).Text= pair.Value 
Next
```

Comment: Furthermore, for anything other than properties that exist on Control (such as .Text), you'd need to cast the return of Me.Controls() into that type:  CType(Me.Controls("txtCustom" & pair.key), TextBox).PasswordChar = "*"  , for example

Comment: Thanks for the help. Me.Controls(String.Format("TxtCustom{0}", pair.Key)).Text = pair.Value is giving me a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" NullReferenceException, I know the key and values exist.

Comment: try replacing the string.format(...) part with a hardcoded string with the exact textbox control name to confirm that the object exists. I tested this code as is with a sample form and it worked fine for me. The only thing I can think is that the pair.key value isn't correct. or the control name doesn't start with "TxtCustom"